# can one intersect a weil divisor and curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

On a projective (integral) variety $X$, is there a well defined notion of the intersection of a Weil divisor and a curve? I know that there is a definition of the intersection of a Cartier divisor and a curve (or dimension 1 cycle), and when $X$ has local rings that are UFDs (e.g. X is smooth) then a Weil divisors and Cartier divisors are in bijective correspondence so in that case the answer to my question is yes. But I can't remember if this is possible in general. A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: If your divisor is not Cartier, but a multiple is, then you can define the intersection by dividing the number obtained by the intersection of the Cartier divisor with the curve. This gives intersection numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc: why not post your good comment as an answer?